# Custom Table names in Identity 2.0, User.IsInRole() not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I tried to rename the tables with the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
}
```

It worked. The table names have been renamed properly, and data seems to be getting inserted in the proper places.

However, The `User.IsInRole("rolestring")` method doesn't work. It returns `false` all the time.
If I remove the above code, everything works fine.
What am I missing?

**Update:**
[image: Here's the database content, just in case it helps]

Comment: When the user signs in there should be an identity object created for that user. See if that object contains role claims.

Answer (score 0):

On your Startup class, when configure the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions, on Provider property you should have a custom class that inherits from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider. In the example below, the **CustomAuthorizationServerProvider** class:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
    Provider = new CustomAuthorizationServerProvider()
};
```

And this is code of CustomAuthorizationServerProvider, where you have to override **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials**:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        ...
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

        if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        IdentityUser user;
        using (AuthRepository repository = new AuthRepository())
        {
            user = await repository.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect");
                return;
            }
        }

        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new AuthDBContext()));
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {
                "as:client_id", context.ClientId ?? string.Empty
            },
            {
                "userName", context.UserName
            },
            {
                "roles",String.Join(",", (IEnumerable<IdentityUserRole>) user.Roles.ToArray())
            }
        });

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

**Note**: AuthDBContext is the same class you are declaring your **OnModelCreating** method.

So, reviewing the code above, you'll check that user roles are inserted in AuthenticationProperties dictionary

```
{
    "roles",String.Join(",", (IEnumerable<IdentityUserRole>) user.Roles.ToArray())
}
```

and then they are inserted in the ticket with the ClaimsIdentity object of the current user.

```
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
```

Once you've fixed this, you only have to add the [Authorize] attribute in your actions and/or controllers like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Or check in your controller actions the equivalent:

```
ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole("Admin")
```

Comment: i am not using `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`

Comment: @gldraphael Why not? You need to add the app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions); to "add OAuth2 Authorization Server capabilities to your OWIN web application. This middleware performs  the request processing for the Authorize and Token endpoints defined by the OAuth2 specification". If not, you User.IsInRole that performs the [Authorize] attribute will not work.